# How can I assign global and local variables in node js

Tags: node.js, httprequest, local, json-web-token

If I declare a variable and assign value from a method and print outside the method.But it shows undefined.
My code is,

```
var value;
var getValue = function getValue(){
    value = 5;
};
console.log(value);
```

Output,

```
undefined
```

I am also trying in global variable

```
var getValue = function getValue(){
    global.value = 5;
};
console.log(value);
```

But shows some errors,

```
console.log(value);
            ^

ReferenceError: value is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/MyApp/test.js:8:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:146:18)
    at node.js:404:3
```

Comment: Well, you must call the function to set the value

Comment: My scenario is that have http post call inside that method and get some response I need to save that value in locally and can I possible this logic.? If I have call a method one more request goes to that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't wait for the callback to be executed.

Instead of

```
app.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
    var userToken;
    ...
    amqHandler.reciveData(amqpConnection ,function(err,data){
        if(!err){
            httpRequestHandler. makeHttpRequest(data, function(err,userToken){
                global.apiResponce = JSON.parse(userToken).token;
                global.convertedObjects = JSON.stringify(apiResponce);
                console.log("convertedObjects==>"+convertedObjects);
                userToken = {token:JSON.stringify(apiResponce)};
            });
        }
    });
    res.send({msg:userToken}); // this is executed before the end of reciveData
});
```

You must send the response *from* the callback passed to the asynchronous function:

```
app.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
    ...
    amqHandler.reciveData(amqpConnection ,function(err,data){
        if(!err){
            httpRequestHandler. makeHttpRequest(data, function(err,userToken){
                global.apiResponce = JSON.parse(userToken).token;
                global.convertedObjects = JSON.stringify(apiResponce);
                console.log("convertedObjects==>"+convertedObjects);
                var userToken = {token:JSON.stringify(apiResponce)};
                res.send({msg:userToken}); // <=== send here
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Note that there are constructs, most notably [promises](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/why-promises.html) which make it easier to chain asynchronous calls. But you must first understand the problem and see how you can handle it with callbacks.

Answer (score 4):

In your first example, value is set in the function but the function is never called. Therefore value is `undefined`.

In the global example, value is never declared and thus not defined.

What you want to do is call getValue() and then output your value to the console.

First example:

```
var value;
var getValue = function(){
    value = 5;
};
getValue();
console.log(value); // should return 5
```

Global example:

```
var global = {}; // create an object otherwise you get a 'global is not defined' error
var getValue = function getValue(){
    global.value = 5;
};
getValue();
console.log(global.value); // should return 5
```

Comment: My scenario is that have http post call inside that method and get some response I need to save that value in locally and can I possible this logic.? If I have call a method one more request goes to that post.

Comment: locally relative to the function? sorry I'm not sure I follow

Answer (score 2):

Your function isn't being run, therefore value is not being set.

```
var value;
var getValue = function getValue(){
    value = 5;
};
getValue(); // call function to set value of 'value'

console.log(value);
```